# Are there any pointers in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, struct

How do i make something like this work in C#?

My teacher's code in C++ defines an object that is the same type as the structure this object is defined in, so logically to avoid StackOverFlowException (objects would be creating and creating other ones) he used pointers.

But i don't know any pointers in C# to do that.

How do i avoid StackOverflowException when defining a struct object in C#?

```
struct HeapNode<T>
{
    T Data;

    HeapNode<T> Right; // in C++ it would be HeapNode* Right
    HeapNode<T> Left;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use *reference* types, change it to a class.

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "avoid cycles"? The C++ you posted doesn't do anything to avoid them, I assume what you mean is to avoid having the struct store the values directly and use pointers to the values.

Comment: @RonBeyer The C++ code uses pointers (see comment next to `Right`). I believe this code is C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there damn sure are pointers in C#, but that's called unsafe code and you can't use them when not specifying, that that is unsafe.

Generic pointers were not allowed until C# 7 point something, but now they're allowed and the code in the question could be written using pointers.

The code in the question could be rewritten as below:

```
unsafe struct HeapNode<T>
{
    T* Data;

    HeapNode<T>* Right; // in C++ it would be HeapNode* Right
    HeapNode<T>* Left;
}
```

When compiling with /unsafe option enabled.

Note that I didn't try to compile not test the code, but that's the starting point for the idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use a class, this way you will have reference types.

```
 public class Node<T>
 {
     public Node<T> Left { get; set; } 
     public Node<T> Right { get; set; } 
     public T Data { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: This does nothing to avoid cycles.

Comment: In C# you mostly use references and not pointers, because of garbage collections. You can have more references to the same objects, the same way as more pointer to the same struct in C++. This is how you should implement it in C#.

Comment: @Servy OP was very probably talking about circular dependency (i.e. the struct not having a defined size because it can't contain itself), not about cycles in the sense of cyclic references (worrying about which isn't really on topic for beginners).

Comment: @Cubic Worrying about cycles in a graph is *super* relevant is you're writing the code for a graph that needs to not have cycles, which tends to be most graphs.

Comment: @Cubic I think that it's not his intention to build graphs ( the structure is not appropriate and in the question it's named a HeapNode), but to make a Heap. In a heap there arent any cycles.

Comment: @Servy You wont be able to build a graph using this structure, because you are limited to two edges per Vertex. To make a graph node you would need a LinkedList<Node> or an array Node[] for all the edges in an undirected graph.

Comment: The think in the question is pretty obviously meant for a min/max heap. Obviously that shouldn't have loops, but that's error condition checking which is usually omitted for example code.

Also, you don't want to avoid cycles in "most graphs". You want to avoid cycles exactly in trees (or DAGs if you mean directed cycles). Trees and DAGs are useful, but hardly "most graphs".

Comment: @AndrejHafner You couldn't build any arbitrary graph, but you can build any graph with no more than two edges per node, and such graphs can certainly still have cycles.

Comment: i meant something like stackoverflow, when structure A creates the same type structure B, although structure A is still not completely defined and structure B is defining its own structure C etc... that's what i meant. Obviously i didn't mean no cycles in binary heap =D
Sorry for misunderstanding